# The webhook returned an HTTP status code other than 200.(401 Unauthorized)

Tags: google-apps-script, line-messenger

I tried to make line chatbot that can setting up an event and notify the user at the setting date with the code down below:

```
function doPost(e) {
 
  const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).events[0];
  
  const lineUserId = data.source.userId;
 
  const replyToken= data.replyToken;
  
  const postMsg = data.message.text;

  
  if(typeof replyToken === 'undefined') {
    return;
  }

  
  const cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  let type = cache.get("type");

  
  if(type === null) {
    if(postMsg === 'add event') {
      cache.put('type', 1);
      reply(replyToken, 'Please add an event description');
    } else if(postMsg === 'delete event'){
      cache.put('type', 3);
      reply(replyToken, 'Please select an event to delete')
    } else if(postMsg === 'event list'){
      reply(replyToken, showEventsList());
    } else {
      reply(replyToken, 'โปรดเลือกพิมพ์คำสั่งที่คุณต้องการ \n[add event]\n[delete event]\n[event list]');
    }
  } else {
    
    if(postMsg === 'cancel') {
      cache.remove('type');
      reply(replyToken, 'cancel event adding');
      return;
    }

    switch(type) {
      case '1':
        cache.put('type', 2);
        cache.put('name', postMsg);
        reply(replyToken, 'ตัวอย่างการเพิ่มวันเกิด ให้พิมพ์รูปแบบนี้ [1996/12/20] \n ถ้าไม่ต้องการแสดงปีเกิด ให้กรอกแค่ เดือน และ วันที่');
        break;
      case '2':
        if(postMsg.match(dateExp || dateExpYear)) {
          cache.put('date', postMsg);
          addBirthday(cache.get('name'), cache.get('date'), lineUserId);
          reply(replyToken, `${cache.get('name')} วันเกิด ${cache.get('date')} บันทึกวันเกิดแล้ว`);
          cache.remove('type');
          cache.remove('name');
          cache.remove('date');
          break;
        } else {
          reply(replyToken, 'ป้อนข้อมูลให้ถูกต้อง ทำการพิมพ์ "ยกเลิก" เพื่อดำเนินการเข้าข้อมูลใหม่');
          break;
        }

      
      case '3':
        if(checkName(postMsg) !== -1) {
          deleteBirthday(checkName(postMsg));
          reply(replyToken, `${postMsg} ได้ทำการลบวันเกิดของเขาแล้ว`);
          cache.remove('type');
          break;
        } else {
          reply(replyToken, `${postMsg} ไม่มีวันเกิดคนนี้ในระบบ`);
          cache.remove('type');
          break;
        }
    }
  }
}


function addBirthday(name, date, lineUserId) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const splitedDate = date.split('/');
  let year, month, day;

  if(splitedDate.length === 3) {
    year = splitedDate[0];
    month = splitedDate[1];
    day = splitedDate[2];

    sheet.appendRow([name, year, month, day, lineUserId]);
  } else {
    year = '';
    month = splitedDate[0];
    day = splitedDate[1];

    sheet.appendRow([name, year, month, day, lineUserId]);
  }
};

function checkName(name) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const nameList = [];
  
  let nameIndex = -1;

  
  for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    nameList.push(values[i][0]);
  }

  
  nameList.forEach((e, i )=> {
    if(e == name) {
      nameIndex = i;
      return;
    }
    return;
  });

  return nameIndex;
}


function deleteBirthday(rowNumber) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  sheet.deleteRows(rowNumber + 1);
}


function showBirthdaysList() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const ranges = sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length - 1, 4).getValues();

  const dataList = ranges.reduce((list, item) => {
    if(item[1] === '') {
      return `${list}\n${item[0]} : ${item[2]}/${item[3]}`;
    } else {
      return `${list}\n${item[0]} : ${item[1]}/${item[2]}/${item[3]}`;
    }
  }, 'รายชื่อ : วันเกิด');

  return dataList;
}


function reply(replyToken, message) {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, {
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    },
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify({
      'replyToken': replyToken,
      'messages': [{
        'type': 'text',
        'text': message,
      }],
    }),
  });
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'content': 'post ok'})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
function pushMessage() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const index = findUser();

  
  if(index === -1) {
    return;
  }

  const person = sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1).getValue();
  const to = sheet.getRange(index + 1, 5).getValue();
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  let theYear = sheet.getRange(index + 1, 2).getValue();
  let message = "วันนี้คุณ ";
  let age;

  if(theYear) {
    age = year - theYear;
    message += `${person} อายุ ${age} เป็นวันเกิดวันนี้!`;
  } else {
    message += `${person} เป็นวันเกิดวันนี้!`;
  }


  return push(message, to);
}

function findUser() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  
  const birthdaysList = values.map( row => {
    return `${row[2]}/${row[3]}`;
  });

  
  const today = new Date(); 
  const hour = today.getHours();
  const month = today.getMonth();
  const date = today.getDate();
 
  const theDay = `${month + 1}/${date}`;

 
  const BirthdayIndex = birthdaysList.findIndex((el) => el == theDay　);



  return BirthdayIndex;
}


function push(message, to) {

    var url = "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push";
    var headers = {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    };
    var postData = {
    "to" : to,
    "messages" : [{
    "type": "flex",
    "altText": "HBD",
    "contents":{
  "type": "bubble",
  "hero": {
    "type": "image",
    "url": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6b/04/fe/6b04fe0cb4e70165f24a94c9dfb146f6.jpg",
    "size": "full",
    "aspectRatio": "20:13",
    "aspectMode": "cover"
  },
  "body": {
    "type": "box",
    "layout": "vertical",
    "contents": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": message,
        "weight": "bold",
        "size": "xl",
        "wrap": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
}],
    };
    var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "headers" : headers,
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(postData)
    };
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

However, there are some information that cannot be provided here.

And when I tried to add webhook to line message api, it response like a picture down below:
[appeared error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7LB5.png)

I coded that script in google script.

Is there any way to fix it?

I expected that the script is able to connect with line message api.